# SSO using SAML in multi tenant application

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml

I need to enable SSO in my and one more application. Both applications are multi-tenant applications. (to log in, user must provide user name, password and tenant name).

Every tenant will have it's own directory in identity provider or use different IDP.

Does it make sense to authenticate the user on identity provider using tenant name beside user name and password?

Is there a IDP solution capable of providing this service? (3 parameter log in)

Comment: What is this tenant in practice? Is is like what department the user is in?

Comment: In practice tenant is different customer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

I would think many of the IDPs out there can be made to take in three parameters. If you are using the common SAML Web SSO spec, I don't see any problem in using SAML.

As an example OpenAM is quite customizable, free and supports SAML.

This is probably of help
https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Write+a+custom+authentication+module

Comment: did you ever use openAM in that way?

Comment: I have not but a college of mine has done similar customization of OpenAM. When customizing a authentication module in OpenAM you basically have a java class implementing an interface. You can do custom ldap operations from there.